# How does prepend preserve immutability of a List but append does not?

Tags: scala, immutability

If we append an element to a list, how is preserving the immutability of the list in Scala? Should not a new list be made? In java if you add a letter to be the first character, then a new String would be made, and strings are immutable in Java. What is the reason for append to be linear time in Scala? Is it to traverse through the whole list and to add at the end or it is linear because we need to create a whole new list since changing the object?

Comment: Who said append did not? Yes it is linear for the reasons you stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both prepend and append to a `List` result in a new `List` and thus preserve immutability of the `List`. We can check this like so

```
val l = List(1)
l.prepended(0)
l.appended(2)
l             // just has List(1) instead of List(0,1,2)
```

Prepend is constant time because it does not copy the entire list. Instead it just creates new object that holds a reference to the new head and the reference to the previous tail.

```
def prepended[B >: A](elem: B): List[B] = elem :: this   // new ::(elem, this)
```

Append is linear time because it does copy the entire list

```
def appended[B >: A](elem: B): CC[B] = {
  val b = iterableFactory.newBuilder[B]
  ...
  b ++= this  // copy of the entire list happens here
  b += elem
  b.result()
}
```

Also note retrieving the last element of a `List` is linear time because `List` is implemented as a *singly* linked list, so it does not know the reference to the last element.

---

Addressing the comment, List can be an efficient structure despite new `List` being returned as long as you use it correctly in prepend fashion. Sometimes you will have to `reverse` the list at the end to get the required order, however this is a one-off traversal. Performance should always in the end be measured within particular circumstance by, say, sbt-jmh.

---

Also be careful not to confuse `Array` with `List`. Former is not really a true Scala collection

```
implicitly[Array[Int] <:< Iterable[Int]] // error
```

which demonstrates `Array` is not a subtype of the base of Scala collections. `Array` is a Java Array and should be used only if measurements absolutely dictate it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to find the time complexity of the creation of the new array since every change leads to new one made?

Comment: @VividMan what do you mean with arrays and changes leading to a new one?

Comment: "Appending to a `List` is linear time because `List` is implemented as a *singly* linked list, so it does not know the reference to the last element." – The (IMO) much more relevant reason it is linear is that it needs to *copy* the entire list, meaning it does not just have linear worst-case *step* complexity, it also has linear worst-case *space* complexity.

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html or older https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html